# How to create manual php header?

Tags: php, header

hello i would like to know how would it be possible to create a manual php header example

```
header("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"$fieldname\"; filename=\"$filename\");
```

instead of using that i would like to create manual it as

```
$senddata = "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"$fieldname\"; filename=\"$filename\"".$nn;
```

Comment: what is your question about? What's the difference between these two? Isn't the first one manual as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This:

```
ob_start();

$senddata = "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"$fieldname\"; filename=\"$filename\"".$nn;

header($senddata);
```

**but make sure that you have constructed the valid header.**

Answer (score 0):

```
ob_start();
.... other stuff ....
$senddata ="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"$fieldname\"; filename=\"$filename\"".$nn;
header($senddata);
```

?

Answer (score 0):

If you need to get the fieldname and filename and some data is outputted before, you can look into [output buffering](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php)